# General server for file sharing and media

Tags: linux, windows, android, network-shares, media-server

I've got a SoC (ODroid) which I'd like to use as a file or media server, I'm not sure how should I call it (let me describe my needs).

I've got an external HDD, which I'd like to share over my LAN. This external HDD would have multiple type of files on it, like media ones (movies, pictures, etc) and other executable types too.

I would like to be able to access this HDD using multiple Laptops (mainly Windows OS) and it would be the best if I could even access it using my android phone.

As I mentioned it, the ext. HDD has movies on it, which I'd like to play on my laptop, thus a "HTTP-like" connection wouldn't be enough, where I have to first download the whole video first. I'd like to peek inside the videos, seek, etc.

What (kind of) server do you recommend for my specific case which is able to handle the cases stated above and available for ODroid (which has 64bit ARM CPU & Ubuntu based OS)?
User management is advantage, but not requirement.

Comment: Sorry, x64 ARM CPU's don't exist. It's either x64 (Intel 64 or AMD64), or ARM (and that might be 64-bit).

Comment: @mtak Thanks, I edited the topic, I hope it's correct now :)

Comment: I'd recommend PLEX media server: https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/146562/plex-in-lubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you run into problems, remember to use an extra power supply for the disk. You can stream most DLNA content easily -> `apt search dlna` ... install the most suitable packages for your needs. Using mkchromecast you can stream both video and music files to a chromecast.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use SSHFS+Samba+DLNA server on it as long you have root access.

SSHFS provides easy access for unix like systems

Samba provides easy access for windows like systems

DLNA provides easy access for Kodi/TV's etc.